# I couldn't run my "dropdown" command. "When you press the button, the links should appear."

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

When I pressed the dropdown button, the links were supposed to be sorted one after the other. But I could not. I am using Bootstrap. I'm almost new to software by the way. It may be an easy question.

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown button
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
    </div>

</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include "popper.js" library. It's what bootstrap uses for dropdown mechanism if i've researched correct. So this code works;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta
    name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
  />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  />

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
      Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the data-bs-toggle="dropdown" attribute to dropdown-toggle button.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen live :
https://codepen.io/Superawdi/pen/jOzYrvX

Comment: ı try but didn't work :(

Comment: check the codepen live : https://codepen.io/Superawdi/pen/jOzYrvX